# Loop returns error: 'argument is of length zero'

Tags: r, runtime-error

```
i <- 2
j <- 0
for (i in 2:1000) {
  if(return.prime(i)){j = j + 1}
  i = i + 1
}
```

---

I want to check how many prime numbers there are in 1 to 1000 using my own function `return.prime` which returns TRUE when the number input is a prime and FALSE when the number input is not prime. The `return.prime` function is the function below and it is correct.

```
return.prime <- function(d){
  if(d ==1 ){print(FALSE)}
  if (d == 2){
    print(TRUE)
  }
  if(d !=2 && d!=1){
      if(any(d %% (2:(d-1)) == rep(0,d-2))==TRUE){
        print(FALSE)}
      else
        print(TRUE)
  }
}
```

The problem is when I run my program it says:

---

```
[1] TRUE
Error in if (return.prime(i)) { : argument is of length zero
```

I do not know what causes the length zero.

Answer (score 1):

R doesn't work that way.  You're just having the function *print the word* "TRUE" or "FALSE".  Instead, you need to [?return](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/function.html) `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  Consider:

```
return.prime <- function(d){
  if(d==1){ return(FALSE) }
  if(d==2){ return(TRUE)  }
  if(d !=2 && d!=1){
      if(any(d %% (2:(d-1)) == rep(0,d-2))==TRUE){
        return(FALSE)
      } else{
        return(TRUE)
      }
  }
}

i <- 2
j <- 0
for (i in 2:1000) {
  if(return.prime(i)){j = j + 1}
  i = i + 1
}
j  # [1] 168
```

Comment: @CatKatherine, if this resolved your issue, you could *accept* it by clicking the check mark below the vote total to its left.